# Public datasets containing less-boring and more detailed data

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for datasets, which allow drilling down to something more spesific and less published than datasets, which can only answer to simple questions like "what is the anti-social behavior rate in certain cities" or "what percent of youngsters are not microchipped".

My intent is to try different JavaScript-libraries for the purpose of presenting data visually. I'd prefer structured data in fileformats like xls, csv and rdf. I also want to challenge myself and force myself to find best ways for letting user of a web-based user interface to feel that he is in control of the information and thus he is able to get insights from it.

Datasets, which I could consider interesting enough include the following examples:

- **work related:** employee names, roles, rooms, buildings, units, departments + employees' work related skillset, their most common personal traits, willingness and ability to learn a, b and/or c
- **mental health related:** people diagnosed as having a schizophrenia, tried treatments, success rates of treating symptoms by changing amount of nutrients, mood changes after jogging
- **sales related:** customer order history, product metadata, task processing times (machines, employees and customers separately), similar products
- **social happenings related:** easiness to approach certain kind of people, typical starting phrases between those who have never met before, less obvious methods for suggesting something

I have a smallish collection of links to the open data portals like [Data.gov.co.uk](http://data.gov.uk/) and [European Union Open Data Portal](http://open-data.europa.eu/en/data/), but I have a feeling that they do not contain, what I'm looking for. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The go-to for random, interesting datasets comes from this article:

**[100+ Interesting Data Sets for Statistics](http://rs.io/100-interesting-data-sets-for-statistics/)**

Here are some quotes from the article based on your question:

- How do gender and mental illness affect crime? [This data set was collected explicitly with that question in mind.](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/studies/27521?q=&paging.rows=25&sortBy=10)
- There’s a lot of data from a series of online personality tests available [here](http://personality-testing.info/_rawdata/).
- [Who receives H1-B visas?](http://www.flcdatacenter.com/CaseH1B.aspx)
- List of the [most frequently searched-for data](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en/us/googleblogs/pdfs/google_public_data_march2010.pdf) (google)

*etc*

Comment: I think I'm most interested about datasets, which allow computer-aided contemplating of future actions and behavior of humans without them answering to questionaries like surveys. Datasets like the ones from the PewResearchCenter are quite interesting as such, but there's not much to do with the data. Last-fm's "similar track" data seemed useful to me as did "Answers to the Experinces in Close Relationships Scale", which follow likert scale, even when it is based on a survey. See also my answer to Anthony.

Answer (score 2):

you are asking for well-organized but rarely-mined microdata.  if you are serious about this project, you need to spend time reviewing the surveys documented on http://asdfree.com/  for example: yrbss has a `number of hours playing on a smartphone` question that can be crosstabulated by hundreds of other survey questions.  you need to spend serious time reading the codebooks.  good luck!  :)

Comment: I'd like to find data that answers to questions like "How did changing of keyboard type for 2000 employees working in 6 different departments affect productivity and what other areas got improved or enhanced because of the change?" Latter part of the question requires data from multiple sources including, but not limited to network routers, authentication servers and local cafeteria (snack consumption).