# What are the most unexpected, weird, crazy or funny open datasets available online?

Tags: data-request

Basicaly everybody is used to usual data like GDP, population, administation budget. So I'm looking some original and unexpected open datasets.

Comment: start here for valid, reliable data on most any topic http://asdfree.com/

Comment: [100+ interest data sets](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4805/1511)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could say that I have spent hours on datasets research and the most unexpected dataset I have found till now is the last words of every inmate executed since 1984 in Texas.

You can find the portal with the data in the official page of Texas here:

http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html

Comment: Woaw, I still can't imagine this dataset exists. Thanks this dataset is really amazing, and disturbing ; and interresting...

Comment: I had the same reaction when I saw it :)

Answer (score 7):

I quite like

- the [Annual statement on the Government Wine Cellar for the financial year 2014 to 2015](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/annual-statement-on-the-government-wine-cellar-for-the-financial-year-2014-to-2015)
- the [Shopping Trolleys Found in Rivers](https://opendata.bristol.gov.uk/Environment/Shopping-Trolleys-Found-in-Rivers/b2rs-9trd)
- and this being Britain the [the Great British Public Toilet Map](http://greatbritishpublictoiletmap.rca.ac.uk/)

Comment: these are great and hilarious

Answer (score 5):

Restaurant food inspections ?

https://opendurham.nc.gov/explore/?q=food+inspection

Crime reports ? Also on durham open data web site.

Your interest will mainly depends on your country or city... it will be interesting if you live in the country of the data provider...

http://data.opendatasoft.com/page/home/ for french people for example